# How to periodically collect hardware performance counters in linux?

Tags: linux, performance-monitoring

I'm trying to monitor various hardware performance counters of a running system, however it seems that current PMC tool e.g. oprofile or perf tool can only record counters after the program finished, e.g. 
`~>perf record <command>;`

`~>perf report`

the perf record returns only after the target program terminates, I'd like to periodically collect these counters like what vmstat does.

Edit: I want to collect **hardware performance counters**, e.g cache-misses,instructions,branch-misses, these counters are available in modern process.

Comment: this SO question has some good responses:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486840/linux-c-how-to-profile-time-wasted-due-to-cache-misses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that current [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) don't support Sar style output. However a very close emulation is possible with the help of watch command.

To collect counters periodically for the whole system,  use the '-a' option.  Below is an example of reporting the general hardware performance counters for every 60 seconds

```
watch -n 60 sudo perf stat -a sleep 60
```

It gives the output as

```
Every 10.0s: sudo perf stat -a sleep 10                                                                                               Wed May 11 11:19:36 2011


 Performance counter stats for 'sleep 10':

       19956.091380  task-clock-msecs         #      1.995 CPUs
              26802  context-switches         #      0.001 M/sec
               1871  CPU-migrations           #      0.000 M/sec
                951  page-faults              #      0.000 M/sec
         4582605668  cycles                   #    229.634 M/sec  (scaled from 69.93%)
         1993617795  instructions             #      0.435 IPC    (scaled from 81.07%)
          374028141  branches                 #     18.743 M/sec  (scaled from 81.34%)
           19071123  branch-misses            #      5.099 %      (scaled from 79.77%)
          100724660  cache-references         #      5.047 M/sec  (scaled from 18.66%)
            5461106  cache-misses             #      0.274 M/sec  (scaled from 20.23%)

       10.001116547  seconds time elapsed
```

The usage of sleep command is a bit counter intuitive at first glance. Here the perf stat will NOT collect counters specific to sleep command ,instead sleep command simply act as a way to tell the perf stat the duration of collection(I realize that from the example in the [perf wiki](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Perf_examples) ) Note to collect system wise counters, administrative privilege is required, so the sudo before perf stat is necessary.

If you simply need collect counters specific to a running process(e.g., with pid 2785), then a sample command is

```
watch -n 60 perf stat -p 2785 sleep 60
```

Note this time, sudo is NOT required.

Answer (score 0):

I find that [sar](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sar) is a simple way to my needs for monitoring a linux system.  It periodically collects stats on many things and you can have cron send you emails periodically with a table of the results which you can then process.

If you need to monitor more systems, or want fancy graphs or alerts, you might look at something like [cacti](http://cacti.net/) or [nagios](http://nagios.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your response, as my new edit of the question, I need hard performance counters e.g cache-misses, not os level metrics e.g. utilization, the later indeed can be fetched from sar/cacti etc.

Answer (score 0):

don't forget collectl.  collects a lot more data and its output is much earier to read than sar.  if you do use sar, do youself a BIG favor and set the monitoring interval to 10 seconds rather than 10 minutes - only real gross problems will show up at a rate as coarse as 10 minutes.
-mark

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log really comprehensive data use Performance Co-Pilot. There's a nice GUI, too.

Comment: Recent pcp versions include two separate agents that gather hardware performance counters: `pmdaperfevent` and `pmdapapi`.